# Survival analysis regression makes little sense

Tags: python, survival, lifelines

I am trying to perform Survival Analysis using Python lifelines library.
My goal is to predict how long will an employee stay in the company before he/she leaves.
My time column is 'time spent at company' and my event column is simply 'left', 0 or 1.

I am using WeibullAFTFitter and I generate survival curves for each individual.
I have two questions:

1. When the survival curve is generated, every individual's curve starts at time zero. Does this mean that I have to substract each individual's time spent at company so I have an actual prediction into the future?
2. My survival curves say that for example when there is an individual with time spent at company 3 years, the probability of the individual surviving two and a half years is less than one, which would make sense to me only if the predicted curves are a prediction for the future and the time spent at company is taken into the account.But that does not look like the case, simply because the probability is one for every person up to 2.4 years. That is probably because no-one has left the company so soon. Take a look at the picture.

[image: Predicted survival curves]

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:** I tried applying the steps laid in [lifelines](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#prediction-on-censored-subjects) documentation , I am not sure if it solved the issue, but there are some new problems ([here](https://imgur.com/a/OYfivmS) is a sample of the output):

- Some individuals have a CONSTANT probability of 1 at each time, even though their input data looks like they should leave soon
- The predictions start from time of 1.5 years (which is the first time somebody left the company), why doesn't it start at time zero though?

**EDIT2:** I trained weibullAFTfitter model on my data and using it's predict_survival_function method on each individual. Worth noting that this is an artificial dataset, just so you know nobody in any company is endangered.

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about how you "generate survival curves for each individual." Is that based on an overall model for all employees that includes employee characteristics, following which you get the overall curve for each individual based on that individual's characteristics? Or is it something else, with separate curves for each individual calculated from the start? Note that a Weibull might not be a good fit for data with a very long period of no events at the start.

Comment: Thank you, I was already thinking about selecting a different model, but I'm going to do it just after I understand the meaning of the predictions a bit better. Editing the post now for clarity.

Comment: The title of your query speaks for itself. You don't discuss what background reading and research, if any, you've done into the theory of survival analysis and how it works. You can't expect to read software code manuals for that.

Comment: What @MikeHunter said! Also: there's a bunch of subtle stuff in the various forms of survival analysis/event history analysis and the study designs that produce the longitudinal data required for survival analysis that can be easy to overlook or counterintuitive (e.g., immortal time bias, left censoring/truncation, the person time versus calendar time, etc.). It is worth spending the time to learn about a particular survival model's ins and outs (and to survey different forms of survival analysis!).